# Tutor LMS not auto logging in

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a wordpress website and using Tutor LMS. It has its own registration page. On the page there is a manual registration and a google SSO. when someone uses google SSO it auto logs in the person and when someone enters name, email etc to register. it reloads to the same page.

```
if ( 'REGULAR_USER' == $payload->role ) {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        $user_login = $payload->preferred_username;
        $user = get_user_by('email', $user_login);
        $user_id = $user->ID;
        clean_user_cache( $user_id);
        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
        wp_set_current_user($user_id, $user_login);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
        do_action('wp_login', $user_login, $user);
        update_user_caches( $user );
    }
 }
```

This was supposed to work according to someone else, but didnt